# Creating MSIX using msbuild produces "doesn't have a target" error but works in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, msbuild, msix

I have three WPF applications that I am including in a MSIX package. I have a solution that contains the three applications along with shared projects and a "Windows Application Packaging Project". I can build the MSIX by Choosing Publish -> Create App Packages on the Packaging project in Visual Studio. I am choosing Sideloading with a self-signed certificate and a Release (Any CPU) option.
[image: Configuration]

This produces the MSIX output as expected.

I'm now trying to do the same thing through MSBuild so that I can integrate this into our automated build system. I'm using the command:

```
MSBuild.exe /restore /p:AppxBundle=Never /p:UapAppxPackageBuildMode=Sideloading  /p:Configuration=Release;Platform="Any CPU" /p:AppxPackageDir=C:\temp\Output\ /p:AppxPackageSigningEnabled=false
```

This produces errors for the WPF applications as per below.

```
:\Repos\app\app.sln" (default target) (1:2) ->
"C:\Repos\app\appPackage\appPackage.wapproj" (default target) (19:6) ->
"C:\Repos\app\app\app.csproj" (publish target) (2:18) ->
  C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\6.0.107\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.PackageDependencyResolution.targets(267,5): error NETSDK1047: Assets file 'C:\Repos\app\app\obj\project.assets.json' doesn't have a target for 'net6.0-windows10.0.19041/win-x86'. Ensure that restore has run and that you have included 'net6.0-windows10.0.19041' in the TargetFrameworks for your project. You may also need to include 'win-x86' in your project's RuntimeIdentifiers. [C:\Repos\app\app\app.csproj]
```

Why does this work in Visual Studio, but no in MSBuild? And how can I get this to work in MSBuild?

Comment: Yesterday we got the same error as you had; one of the issues we had to solve was: signing a MSIX on Windows Server 2016 does not work, since MSIX are not supported on Server2016, only on Server2019+. Our workaround for the moment is, using a Win10VM for the signing Job.

Comment: I was unable to resolve this issue. Instead we moved away from building the MSIX package through Visual Studio / MSBuild. Instead we moved to MSIX Hero (https://msixhero.net/) for building the MSIX and that is working really well for us.

Answer (score 0):

The way msbuild works in visual studio is quite different from msbuild command being run from the command line. Visual studio has their own set of targets, they generate runtimeidenfiers even if not present from the build configuration through custom targets, for reference you can see the build logs while building your project. The best option is to auto generate runtimeidentifiers based on the configuration of the project and use it as parameter in msbuild command as '/p:RuntimeIdentifiers="win-x86"'. Dont forget to forcefully remove the obj and bin folder using this command "Get-ChildItem .\ -include bin,obj -Recurse | foreach { remove-item $_.fullname -Force -Recurse }" before executing msbuild command